# Disintegration theorem, a reference needed

Tags: reference-request, probability-theory

I've come a cross the so called 'disintegration theorem' in multiple occasions now and I'm interested to learn its proof and more on related topics. Particularly I'm interested in a proof for the formulation presented by Wikipedia http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disintegration_theorem .

However, the reference that Wikipedia provides is a very old book (from the 70's with no fancy latex styling) and I can't find other than the oldest version of it. Most of the notations embed very unreadably and awkwardly to the text that I haven't succeeded to follow his arguments so far (could be just unpatiency) and I'm looking for another source that is more readable. If someone has a newer textbook covering this topic then I would be glad to look it up and study this subject.

Also, any kind of discussion about this theorem and its applications are warmly welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't this equivalent to the existence of regular conditional probabilities?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional probability and the disintegration theorem](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/108740/conditional-probability-and-the-disintegration-theorem)

Comment: @StefanHansen: Could be, I'm not that familiar with conditional probability theory. If you can point some sources then I would be glad to go them through. And for others: I'm also looking for sources that deal with general metric spaces (locally compact Polish, compact?) with the push-forward framework and disintegration. Mainly in non probabilistic setting.

Comment: About general metric spaces: did you open at least once Billingsley's book mentioned in my answer?

Comment: @did: Yes, I have that book in my shelf and I'm reading it as we speak. However, I couldn't find anything related to what you suggest. My best guess would be that this topic could be covered under Chapters 6.33-34, but it looks like they aren't. Maybe he covers these topics with different terminology, but I highly doubt it would be dealt before the Radon-Nikodym section. Altogether, so far I haven't been successful in finding this book useful in this particular context.

Comment: Since none of the (so far) provided books have met my interests and this is a rather important matter for me, I have raised a 50 rep bounty for this question.

Comment: I would like to raise a level of (humorous) awareness that books from the 70's are now considered "really old."

Comment: If you are not finding what you need in standard reference books, maybe you ought to ask a more specific question. What *precisely* are you looking for?

Comment: @EdGorcenski. You ignored the second part of the sentence which gave some specification on its style. The book in question is (most likely, judging from its appearance) written with a typewriter machine.

Comment: @ThomasE Oh I was quite aware. I was mostly musing on the particular choice of verbiage. Computer-based typesetting has been around for far less time than it has not; certainly it has been in widespread use for fewer years than I have been breathing, and I hesitate to call myself "very old." It is a simple matter of relativity :)

Comment: @EdGorcenski Interestingly, the previous 1966 version of the book, written by Meyer alon, is professionally typeset. Sadly, it doesn't contain the disintegration theorem.

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: I'm looking for something covering the existence of disintegrations in atleast as general setting as presented in Wikipedia, which is Radon spaces. Particularly I would be prefer to avoid probabilistic conditioning approaches and keep it on a general level. I think Fremlin's book was a perfect match for this search, but in any case, I'm grateful for every answer made in this topic.

Comment: The disintegration theorem for Radon spaces can also be found in Appendix 3 of *General Theory of Markov Processes* by Michael Sharpe. I hope you find what you are looking for!

Comment: @ByronSchmuland: Thanks, I will also look that up :-)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

The most comprehensive account of disintegration can be found in David Fremlin's magnum opus [Measure Theory](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm) in Chapter 45 in Volume 4.1. But this is certainly overkill.

The state of the art paper is [Disintegration and Compact Measures](https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/11771/9787) by Jan Pachl, he gives a characterization result and nothing more general is possible. His approach is based on the von Neumann-Maharam lifting theorem and this approach to disintegrations was pioneered by Hoffmann-Jorgensen in [Existence of Conditional Probabilities](https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/11023/9044). The approach based on liftings has the advantage that it needs no separability conditions, the cost is that the disintegrations are only measurable with respect to a completion.

Under separability assumptions, there are necessary and sufficient conditions known for certain kinds of disintegrations. You can find very useful results to this effect in a beautiful paper by Arnold Faden: [The Existence of Regular Conditional Probabilities: Necessary and Sufficient Conditions](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-probability/volume-13/issue-1/The-Existence-of-Regular-Conditional-Probabilities--Necessary-and-Sufficient/10.1214/aop/1176993081.full).

Now these paper represent the high end of mathematical probability theory. For most applications, one can use much more elementary methods. For conditioning on $\mathbb{R}$, the book by Lehmann and Romano already mentioned gives a very readable proof under Theorem 2.5.1 (2005 ed.). In Billingsley's, *Probability and Measure*, 3rd ed, you can find the same result in section 33 as Theorem 33.3. This results are more powerful than it may seem at first. By a famous isomorphism theorem, every uncountable, separable and complete metric space endowed with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra is isomorphic as a measurable space to $\mathbb{R}$ with the Borel $\sigma$-algebra. If you want to see a proof of the strong version of the result without using this isomorphism theorem, you can check Theorem 10.2.2 in Dudley's *Real Analysis and Probability* (2002/2004 version). The proof in Dudley is considerably harder.

Comment: So far Fremlin's book has been the most impressive and it is exactly what I was looking for. Not only is this opus amazing but so are his other books of the same 'series'. I also looked up rest of your suggestions and they were useful too, thank you. The bounty can be awarded after 1 hour, so until then if nothing better (which I doubt) appears then it surely belongs to this answer.

Comment: I don't usually edit other people's posts, so please note that the link to Pachl's aritcle has become invalid. A new one is http://www.mscand.dk/article/view/11771/9787. Also, his theorem only proves existence, without concern for uniqueness.

Comment: @AlexM. Thank you forpointing the link rot out. I think outside the coutably generated case, uniqueness is too much to hope for.

Comment: I have included the [current website for Fremlin's book](https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm). I wasn't sure whether to include [a Wayback Machine snaphost](http://web.archive.org/web/20231010050735/https://www1.essex.ac.uk/maths/people/fremlin/mt.htm) into the answer - in case the location of the website changes again.

Answer (score 7):

A nice book on [Measure Theory](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/3540345132) by Bogachev deals with disintegration in Chapter 10 (Volume 2).

Comment: Theorem 10.4.8./Example 10.4.11. in the aforementioned book were exactly what I was looking for. Thank you :)

Answer (score 5):

Chapter 6 of *Foundations of Modern Probability (Second edition)* by Olav Kallenberg
 starts with the sentence

> "Modern probability theory can be said to begin with the notions 
>   of conditioning and disintegration."

I think you will find the whole chapter a useful reference.

Answer (score 2):

From the other page:

- [Testing Statistical Hypotheses](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1441931783) by Lehmann and Romano.
- [Probability and Measure](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0471007102) by Billingsley.

Answer (score 1):

Pollard's book "A User's Guide to Measure Theoretic Probability" is very insightful in regard to relating disintegration and conditional probabilities.

Here: http://www.stat.yale.edu/~pollard/

Answer (score 1):

Check out the paper Graf, S., and Mauldin, R. D. A classification of disintegrations of measures. In *Measure and measurable dynamics (Rochester, NY, 1987)*, no. 94 in Contemp. Math. Amer. Math. Soc., Providence, RI, 1989, pp. 147-158.

[This link](https://itservices.cas.unt.edu/%7Emauldin/papers/no73.pdf) works.

Answer (score 0):

See also *Integration and Probability* by Paul Malliavin, second edition (1993), Theorem 6.5.1 (page 227).