# Disintegration of probability measures, reference request

Tags: probability-theory, reference-request, probability-distributions

Do you have a complete reference for disintegration of probability measures? 
Is there only the disintegration theorem, or is there a whole theory?

Thanks.

Comment: Go to this discussion: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175862/disintegration-theorem-a-reference-needed

Comment: Oh thank you so much!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disintegration theorem, a reference needed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/175862/disintegration-theorem-a-reference-needed)